# Is it possible to make an app that detects other devices location using Python?

Tags: python, windows

I am currently learning Python and I am wondering if I can build an application that can detect other devices using WiFi or nearby Bluetooth scanning.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to list the devices listening on wifi, but not their location.